# Understanding nested Loopee tag output

Tags: plugin, loop

I decided to undertake cleaning up some crazy repetitive code using the [plugin Loopee](https://github.com/danott/ee-loopee), which we are already using. I briefly looked at Loop Plus, but that seems to only handle numbers, so I didn’t try testing nesting that one.

Anyway, I tried nesting Loopee tags, and the order the tags are looped is from the inside, opposite of how it would work if these were PHP loops. **I’d like to know if anyone has experience nesting Loopee tags, why this works like this, and how I might resolve this issue.** I’m not averse to patching the plugin if I can get some guidance on what I’d need to do.

An example:

```
{exp:loopee parse="inward" foreach="A|B" as="a"}
  {exp:loopee parse="inward" foreach="1|2" as="b"}
    {exp:loopee parse="inward" foreach="a|b" as="c"}
      {a}{b}{c}
    {/exp:loopee}
  {/exp:loopee}
{/exp:loopee}
```

Output: `A1a B1a A2a B2a A1b B1b A2b B2b`

As you can see, the outer Loopee tag’s `A` and `B` are alternating, while the innermost Loopee tag’s `a` and `b` are not alternating. To solve this simple example, I could swap the innermost and outermost Loopee tags, but that is both wonky and breaks code if I make use of the variables between the first Loopee start tag and the second.

For example, this is what I might like to do:

```
{exp:loopee parse="inward" foreach="amy|betty" as="name"}
  <h1>{name}</h1>
  {exp:loopee parse="inward" foreach="income|expenses" as="category"}
    <h2>{category}</h2>
    {exp:loopee parse="inward" foreach="1|2|3|4" as="quarter"}
      <p>
        <strong>{quarter}:</strong> {custom_field_here}
      </p>
    {/exp:loopee}
  {/exp:loopee}
{/exp:loopee}
```

But if I run that, I get the messed up looking output of (blank lines removed):

```
<h1>amy</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
```

When what I want is output like this:

```
<h1>amy</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
<h1>betty</h1>
  <h2>income</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
  <h2>expenses</h2>
    <p><strong>1:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>2:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>3:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
    <p><strong>4:</strong> {custom_field_here}</p>
```

I am using EE 2.7.2

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone has a better solution than this, but for the time being, I found I can make copies of the Loopee plugin for each level of nesting I need. For example, I would duplicate the `loopee` directory and name it `loopee2`, and then rename the contained file `pi.loopee2.php`. Then I edit that file, changing these lines:

```
'pi_name'         =>  'Loopee2',
class Loopee2 {
function Loopee2()
```

That allows me to use a second level of nesting by calling the tag `{exp:loopee2}`.

(I also [submitted an issue](https://github.com/danott/ee-loopee/issues/5) to the Github repo in case the plugin author has time and desire to tackle the issue.)